# Populate GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I cant populate grid view with the data sent to api. tell me where is the flaw. I have no idea.

```
  protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    WSmyWebAPI.myWeb wsAPI = new WSmyWebAPI.myWeb();
    WSmyWebAPI.OrderSearchParameters sSearchParameters = new
    WSmyWebAPI.OrderSearchParameters();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DateTime dtmStartDate;
    DateTime dtmEndDate;

    dtmStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpApproved.Text);
    dtmEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dpShipped.Text);
    oid = txtOrderID.Text;
    opid = txtPartID.Text;

    sSearchParameters.StartDate = dtmStartDate;
    sSearchParameters.EndDate = dtmEndDate;
    sSearchParameters.OrderID = oid;
    sSearchParameters.OrderPartID = opid;

    ds = wsAPI.OrderSearch(sSearchParameters);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

}

Comment: Is your dataset empty?

Comment: what do you mean empty? when a user type a input on txtOrderID it will be put on sSearchParameters right? then ds = wsAPI.OrderSearch(sSearchParameters); thats where the data are.. or Im wrong? please enlighten me.

Comment: Well 1) I don't know what data you have in your system 2) I don't know if `wsAPI.OrderSearch()` works properly. So the most obvious thing would be to add the EmptyDataText property to your GridView and see if it comes up empty.

Comment: I see. OrderSearch contains a list of data (order id, order part id etc.) How can I know why I cant call it back to gridview/

Comment: Like I said, you need to give us more details. Post the implementation of `OrderSearch()` and provide some examples of the data it's pulling from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a **sample code**. You may manipulate or adjust your code accordingly.
Make sure you have aspx code in place as well. That means the columns you want to display. Try to add

**`GridView1.Vissible = True`**

Further make sure to add a `try catch` block and check on `SqlException`. Try to go on line by line debug mode. I would suggest to display the error on a label in the webpage until your entire page is bug free. So you know where and what went wrong.

As for a suggestion, it's better to take out the connection , query parameter portion out Go click event. Add a separate method to do that. Only get the data set or data table (I recommend data table) and set it to gridview under Go click event.

Comment: Glad it did :) and [please check on why this property of GridView is important at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)